# Can extend be used with defrecord in Clojure 1.4.0?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to use 'extend' to define record methods with a map in Clojure. The following works in Clojure 1.4.0:

```
(defprotocol PointMethods
  (add [self other])
  (distance [self]))

(defrecord Point [x y]
  PointMethods
  (add [self other]
    (Point. (+ (:x self) (:x other)) (+ (:y self) (:y other))))
  (distance [self]
    (Math/sqrt (+ (* (:x self) (:x self)) (* (:y self) (:y self))))))

(def p1 (Point. 2 3))
(def p2 (Point. 1 1))

(def p3 (add p1 p2))
(println p3)
(println (distance p3))
```

But this version fails:

```
(defprotocol PointMethods
  (add [self other])
  (distance [self]))

(defrecord Point [x y])
(extend Point
  PointMethods
  {:add
   (fn [self other] (Point. (+ (:x self) (:x other)) (+ (:y self) (:y other))))
   :distance
   (fn [self] (Math/sqrt (+ (* (:x self) (:x self)) (* (:y self) (:y self)))))})

(def p1 (Point. 2 3))
(def p2 (Point. 1 1))

(def p3 (add p1 p2))
(println p3)
(println (distance p3))

Clojure Compiler: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :add 
of protocol: #'user/PointMethods found for class: user.Point, compiling:(records.clj:16)]
```

What is wrong with the second version?

Comment: I don't think it will fix your immediate problem, but you've misspelled distance as distence in one place, which will eventually cause a new problem.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code into a fresh REPL running clojure 1.4.0 and it works for me (except for Amalloy's correction)

Comment: I just tried it in Clojure 1.5.0 and my code worked fine. Then I tried it in a freshly installed 1.4.0 and my code also worked fine. I think this may in fact be an IDEA / La Clojure issue. It still does not work in a Clojure file or from the repl when in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted in their comments to your code, your code as written works fine in Clojure 1.4.0 (I just verified it myself). You are likely running into some sort of IDE misconfiguration, or perhaps there was some stale cached bytecode.